# Calculate difference in rows with constraints

Tags: r, dataframe

Taking the following dataset:

```
df <- data.frame (Field = c(rep(c("F1","F2","F3"),each=3),rep(c("F4","F5"),each=2)),
              Plot  = c(rep(c("A","B","C"),3),rep(c("A","B"),2)),
              Value = runif(13, min = 0, max = 10),
              Variation = NA
              )
```

Lets say that **Plot A** is the control Plot. I would like to calculate the variation of **plot A** and the others (B and C). The output should appear in column **Variation**.

My actual data-frame is far more extent and complicated, but I guess that this is a good start.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: De difference between means or between what?

Comment: just the difference of values, literally A-B 
But since my dataset is quite large, I am trying to built a function to perform that task, but with no success

Comment: Sorry @Rui I just understood it, I think I can manage to do it.

Comment: question edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found an answer, it took me a while:

I now divided the answer in two parts to show the original answer and the added request of the Rui

## 1 Solution for all against all:

```
df <- data.frame (Field = c(rep(c("F1","F2","F3"),each=3),rep(c("F4","F5"),each=2)),
              Plot  = c(rep(c("A","B","C"),3),rep(c("A","B"),2)),
              Value = runif(13, min = 0, max = 10),
              Total = NA
)
```

Then with this loop

```
Diff<- list()

for(i in 1:length(unique(df$Field))){
  temp <- dplyr::filter(df, Field == unique(Field)[i])
  Plots <- unique(temp$Plot)
  Combinations <- expand.grid(x = Plots, y = Plots)
  Combinations$Plots <- paste(Combinations$x, Combinations$y, sep ="-")
  Combinations$Field <- unique(df$Field)[i]

  Diff[[i]]<- Combinations
}

Diff <- do.call("rbind", Diff)
```

This will make a Data frame with all combinations of plots and fields, then we will use `dplyr::filter` to get the values of x and y with Field

```
Diff$Diff <- NA
for(j in 1:nrow(Diff)){
  Diff[j,]$Diff <- (dplyr::filter(df, Plot == Diff$x[j] & Field == Diff$Field[j])$Value - dplyr::filter(df, Plot == Diff$y[j] & Field == Diff$Field[j])$Value)
}
```

Finally eliminate the first two columns (x and y) to leave 3 columns Plots, Field and  Diff

```
Diff <- Diff[,-(1:2)]
```

Hope it helps, this is a sample of how it looks:

```
head(Diff)
   Plots Field       Diff
1   A-A    F1  0.00000000
2   B-A    F1 -1.25081916
3   C-A    F1 -1.20700858
4   A-B    F1  1.25081916
5   B-B    F1  0.00000000
6   C-B    F1  0.04381059
```

## 2 Solution first against all:

```
Diff<- list()

for(i in 1:length(unique(df$Field))){
  temp <- dplyr::filter(df, Field == unique(Field)[i])
  Plots <- unique(temp$Plot)
  Combinations <- expand.grid(x = Plots[1], y = Plots)
  Combinations$Plots <- paste(Combinations$x, Combinations$y, sep ="-")
  Combinations$Field <- unique(df$Field)[i]

  Diff[[i]]<- Combinations
}

Diff <- do.call("rbind", Diff)

Diff$Diff <- NA
for(j in 1:nrow(Diff)){
  Diff[j,]$Diff <- (dplyr::filter(df, Plot == Diff$x[j] & Field == Diff$Field[j])$Value - dplyr::filter(df, Plot == Diff$y[j] & Field == Diff$Field[j])$Value)
}

Diff <- Diff[,-(1:2)]
```

Comment: Just `merge(df, df, by="Field")` or the dplyr/data.table equivalent would give you a dataset of all the matches within each field.

Comment: @Derek. excellent work. however there is another issue. I just want per field A-A,A-B and A-C (idem for the others). 
hence is it possible to input that constraint in the line: `Combinations$Plots <- paste(Combinations$x, Combinations$y, sep ="-")` 

@thelatemail, the issue is the same as above.
The total number of observations (or lines)  needs to remain the same 

Many thanks

Comment: @Rui, so for everyone, just the first class against the others? is that the objective?

Comment: Yes, that is it. A against all (including A itself)

Comment: @Rui I added your request as solution 2 in the answer, the only change is `Combinations <- expand.grid(x = Plots, y = Plots)` to `Combinations <- expand.grid(x = Plots[1], y = Plots)`

Comment: @Derek Excellent. it works perfectly.
I have add another line, just to be sure that the fields match properly `Match       = match("A",Plots, nomatch = 0)`
(before the line: `Plots <- unique(temp$Plot)`)

Comment: Nice glad it worked I am sorry you got -3 in  your question